# Are there any use cases for this function : foo :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)

Tags: haskell

For this function :

`foo :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`

taken from http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/04-higher-order.html

Is this a function with no practical use ? As `(b -> c)` cannot be constructed unless type c is another input parameter within this function ?

And same for `(a -> b) -> (a -> c)` : b & c are not input parameters to these functions.

Are there any use cases for this function ?

Comment: What do mean by meaningless? It is a composition of two functions. Btw, the linked article clearly states it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question is about using function composition in practice, here is a small example. Let's assume that we want to write a function which the sum of squares of all elements of a list of numbers. How could we do that? Well, we could write something like: `squareSum xs = sum (map (^2)) xs`. But we can also use function composition instead: `squareSum = sum . map (^2)`(I use `.` for function composition here instead of `foo`, but it doesn't really matter). This example shows a function which is obtained using function composition(it is practical at least in a sense that it compiles and works correctly). The benefits of function composition become more obvious when we need to compose multiple functions(possibly partially applied).

Answer (score 2):

The function `b -> c` can be constructed - since `b` and `c` can be any type, then any function is compatible with it. However the function `foo` cannot *itself* (sensibly) construct such a function since it has no knowledge of `b` and `c`. This is a great benefit since it greatly reduces the number of possible implementations of the function `foo`. This is called [parametricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity)

This function is the type of the function composition operator `(.)`:

Comment: *it greatly reduces the number of possible implementations of the function foo* - is there even *one* implementation different from the regular one?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - I don't think so, I'm sure someone more knowledgeable than me could prove it.

Comment: I believe `f=(.)` should follow by considering a normalized natural deduction proof of the corresponding proposition. Or possibly from its free theorem (even though I just failed a quick attempt to this).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz `undefined`, `\_ -> undefined`, `\_ _ -> undefined`, and `\_ _ _ -> undefined` all have the given type and are different in meaningful ways from the regular one. There are also many variants like `\f -> f \`seq\` \g x -> f (g x)` that force their arguments at different times. Some of these are not only different but also useful.

Answer (score 0):

I just would like to chime in that `(.)` is probably somewhere in the top-three most-used functions in any good Haskell codebase.  It certainly is in my code.

The other two of the top three are implicit calls to `fromInteger` inserted by the compiler due to integral literals, and implicit calls to `(>>=)` from `do` notation. And the latter there is, in a deep sense, the same operation as `(.)` but on values with slightly-differently-shaped types.

Answer (score 0):

To complement other answers, let me try to prove that there is only one (total) function

```
foo :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

or, in other words, that `foo = (.)`. By extensionality, we want to prove

```
foo f g n = f (g n)
```

where `f,g,n` are abritrary values of the types mandated by the signature of `foo`.

```
f :: b -> c
g :: a -> b
n :: a
```

We start from the associated free theorem, which can be [automatically generated on the web](http://www-ps.iai.uni-bonn.de/cgi-bin/free-theorems-webui.cgi):

```
forall t1,t2 in TYPES, R in REL(t1,t2).
 forall t3,t4 in TYPES, S in REL(t3,t4).
  forall t5,t6 in TYPES, R1 in REL(t5,t6).
   forall p :: t3 -> t5.
    forall q :: t4 -> t6.
     (forall (x, y) in S. (p x, q y) in R1)
     ==> (forall r :: t1 -> t3.
           forall s :: t2 -> t4.
            (forall (z, v) in R. (r z, s v) in S)
            ==> (forall (w, u) in R.
                  (foo p r w, foo q s u) in R1))
```

Let's simplify this huge formula by specializing it. We pick:

```
t1 = a    t2 = ()
t3 = b    t4 = ()
t5 = c    t6 = ()
```

and we choose the relations as follows:

```
R = { (n       , ()) }  which is indeed in REL(t1,t2) = REL(a,())
S = { (g n     , ()) }  which is indeed in REL(t3,t4) = REL(b,())
R1= { (f (g n) , ()) }  which is indeed in REL(t5,t6) = REL(c,())
```

The free theorem becomes:

```
   forall p :: b -> c.
    forall q :: () -> ().
     (forall (x, y) in S. (p x, q y) in R1)
     ==> (forall r :: a -> b.
           forall s :: () -> ().
            (forall (z, v) in R. (r z, s v) in S)
            ==> (forall (w, u) in R.
                  (foo p r w, foo q s u) in R1))
```

Picking `p = f` and `q = id` we obtain, by definition of `S` and `R1`:

```
     (forall x = g n, y = () . f x = f (g n) /\ y = id y)
     ==> (forall r :: a -> b.
           forall s :: () -> ().
            (forall (z, v) in R. (r z, s v) in S)
            ==> (forall (w, u) in R.
                  (foo f r w, foo id s u) in R1))
```

The premise of the top-level implication is true, so we discharge it.
We now pick `r = g` and `s = id`. We get, by definition of `r1` and `R`:

```
            (forall z = n, v = () . g z = g n , id v = ())
            ==> (forall (w, u) in R.
                  (foo f g w, foo id id u) in R1)
```

We can discharge the true premise. Further, we can pick `w = n` and `u = ()`. We finally obtain:

```
                  foo f g n = f (g n) /\ foo id id u = ()
```

**Q.E.D.**